# Topology objective question based on homeomorphism .

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following sets of $\Bbb R^2$ with usual topology

$$X=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1\}\cup \{(x,y)\mid (x-2)^2+y^2<1\}$$

$$Y=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1\}\cup \{(x,y)\mid (x-3)^2+y^2<1\}$$

$$Z=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2<1,x\neq 0\}$$ then which of the following sets are homeomorphic ?

$1.$ all of $X,Y,$ and $Z$.

$2.$ none of $X,Y$ and $Z$.

$3.$ $X$ and $Z$ only .

$4.$ $ X$ and $Y$ only .

$ 5.$ $Y$ and $Z$ only .

For me it seems that all are homeomorphic to each other as all of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ has two components and corresponding components are homeomorphic. Am I right ? Please suggest me for correct options. Thank you .

Comment: Sorry, you’re right: I misread it and thought that only the origin had been deleted. So you are quite right: all three are homeomorphic.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott thank you sir .

Comment: You’re welcome; sorry about the confusion on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, all three spaces consist of two disjoint components, both of which are (homeomorphic to) an open unit disk in the plane. So they are all mutually homeomorphic.